# Botframework | Twilio WhatsApp Adapter: how to fix "request doesn't contain a valid Twilio Signature"

Tags: botframework, twilio-api

I need to use Twilio as a channel for a chatbot (Bot Framework V4 NodeJS and the Twilio WhatsApp Adapter)
Messages send to Twilio via WhatsApp do reach the chatbot as a request. In the chatbot itself the validation of the request keeps failing.

```
const { TwilioWhatsAppAdapter } = require('@botbuildercommunity/adapter-twilio-whatsapp');
const whatsAppAdapter = new TwilioWhatsAppAdapter({
    accountSid: '<Sid from Twilio console >', 
    authToken: '<>Auth token from Twilio console', 
    phoneNumber: '<phone number from Whatsapp Sandbox settings in Twilio>',
    endpointUrl: 'url from Sandbox setting in Twilio' 
});
```

The adapter is using a Twilio module. Twilio.validateRequest keeps returning false.

```
const signature = req.headers['x-twilio-signature'] || req.headers['X-Twilio-Signature'];
const authToken = this.settings.authToken;
const requestUrl = this.settings.endpointUrl;
const message = await this.retrieveBody(req);
return Twilio.validateRequest(authToken, signature, requestUrl, message);
```

I would appreciate some guidance. Otherwise I will need to figure our a way to debug this module
tnx

For the endpointUrl parameter I use is the one from my chatbot: https://mybot.azurewebsites.net/api/whatsapp/messages

for the phoneNumber parameter I tried multiple formats without succes:
whatsapp:+1XXXXXXXXXX
whatsapp:1XXXXXXXXXX
+1XXXXXXXXXX
1XXXXXXXXXX

I checked the source of the adapter and there are two possible causes.

1. No x-twilio-signature header. I checked the request headers and there seems to be a valid x-twilio-signature header in there.
2. The result of the twilio.validateRequest returns false. This method is taking authToken, signature, requestUrl and message. I checked them all and they seem fine.

Comment: The issue is almost certainly in the values you are passing in as neither the Twilio- nor the BotBuilder-Community adapter-related code has been updated in 3-4 years. For the phone number, have you tried `whatsapp: +1XXXXXXXXXX` with a space following the colon? I would suggest going over your various property values to be doubly certain each is formatted correctly (i.e., no extra spaces, missing characters, etc.).

Comment: I would also suggest setting up some breakpoints and stepping thru while debugging when first connecting to see what the adapter and Twilio module is actually getting.

Comment: Thanks Steven. I will start with the sample just to make sure it is not  in my botcode. Wrt the phonenumber, I checked and it not used to validate request. So my problem should be in authToken, signature, requestUrl or the message.

Comment: update: Sample works ok with the same values I used in my own bot. Time to look for differences

Comment: The cause: server.use(require('body-parser').json());
Not sure why it is there in the first place since I am using restify